# Provide MySQL-to-Sqlite type compatibility with python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I need to read data from MySQL, process it with python script and write the result into Sqlite.
Also, I need to convert MySql create definitions to Sqlite create definitions.
Are there any existing libraries for python to convert MySql data type (including `set`, `enum`, `timestamp`, etc.) to Sqlite data type, or I should write it myself?

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124162/python-copy-mysql-table-to-sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you could use an ORM library like [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) for abstracting away the MySQL and Sqlite databases.

One possible way of approaching your problem would be to use peewee's [model generator](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#generating-models-from-existing-databases) for creating models for the MySQL database, which you can later reuse for the Sqlite one using [this example](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#using-multiple-databases) as reference.